# uploading to ftp from terminal

Tags: ftp, terminal

I have a huge repository of files and there is a .txt containing a large list that needs to be uploaded to an ftp server. I don't have ssh access. Is there an easy way to automate this using terminal so I don't have to go into ftp and manually go up and down the folders?

Thanks

{EDIT}
I am using os x. I have fetch as a client.

Comment: What operation system are you using? What is your ftp client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a terminal program such as:

$ wput --help

Usage: wput [options] [file]... [url]...
  url        ftp://[username[:password]@]hostname[:port][/[path/][file]]

it works on windows as well